# Conversion of mainframe S370 hexadecimal floating–point to decimal

Tags: python

I am reading a binary file from the mainframe and I would like to convert the single precession floating point numbers which are currently represented in HEX to be converted to its decimal equivalent in python. For example

X'42808000' ==> should be converted to 128.50 in decimal..
X'C2808000' ==> should be converted to -128.50 in decimal

Are they any built in functions in python that does this. It looks like the internal floating representations are not in IEEE format but the old "S370 mainframe hexadecimal format". Kindly let me know your thoughts on how to convert the same. Thanks

Comment: You need to find or figure out the :"old S370" binary format (I doubt it's hexadecimal characters), then you can determine the operation necessary to convert it into a Python float. I'm sure it's documented somewhere.

Comment: I got a document that show on how the conversion is done...but I am not sure how to put that in a piece of code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks http://www.edwardbosworth.com/My3121Textbook_HTM/MyText3121_Ch17_V02.htm (example 1 and 2)

Comment: Okay, but I won't be able to look into it until later this morning my time (it's almost 2:00 AM right now). One thing I noticed in the linked document that I don't understand. It says "Recalling that the range for integers stored in 7–bit unsigned format is 0 £ N £ 127, we have 0 £ (E + 64) £ 127, or –64 £ E £ 63." What do the £ characters mean, <=?

Comment: Yes that is correct its lessthanorequal to (<=)

Comment: Thanks for your time Martineau

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question where you say the numbers are currently represented in HEX, for the format of the S370 hexadecimal floating-point numbers, whether you meat that they're binary integer or string values, so I wrote a function that will accept either one.

```
try:
    basestring
except NameError:  # Python 3
    basestring = str

def hextofp(hexadecimal):
    """ Convert S370 hexadecimal floating-point number to Python
        binary floating point value (IEEE 754).
    """
    v = int(hexadecimal, 16) if isinstance(hexadecimal, basestring) else hexadecimal
    if v:  # not special case of "True 0"
        sign = -1 if v & 0x80000000 else 1
        exponent = ((v & 0x7f000000) >> 24) - 64  # remove bias
        fraction = float(v & 0x00ffffff) / 16777216  # divide by 2**24
        return sign * (fraction * 16**exponent)
    return 0.0

print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('42808000')))  # -> 128.50
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp(0x42808000)))  # -> 128.50
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('C2808000')))  # -> -128.50
print('{:.3f}'.format(hextofp('40600000')))  # -> 0.375

# True 0
print('{:.1f}'.format(hextofp('00000000')))  # -> 0.0
# largest representable number
print('{:.8g}'.format(hextofp('7fffffff')))  # -> 7.2370051e+75
# smallest positive (normalized) number
print('{:.8g}'.format(hextofp('00100000')))  # -> 5.3976053e-79

# misc examples
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('42500000')))  # -> 80.00
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('41100000')))  # -> 1.00
print('{:.3f}'.format(hextofp('C276A000')))  # -> -118.625
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('427b3333')))  # -> 123.20
print('{:.2f}'.format(hextofp('427b7333')))  # -> 123.45
```

Comment: Awesome...It worked perfectly fine....Thank you very much for all your help...I will check your code to see how exactly its done...